# How to get the total value of number after increment

Tags: angular, angular5

I am very new in learning's about Angular 5 and I just wanna ask on how to get the total value of number after it increment.

So far I am following the tutorial and I am using the `*ngFor` but what I want is this...

[image]

but what I got is this.

[image]

and this is my code.

```
<div class="card-footer clearfix" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="float-left p-2">
        <i class="fa fa-circle green-text" aria-hidden="true" mdbTooltip="Active Item" placement="bottom"></i><small class="text-muted"> 0</small>
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o grey-text ml-3" aria-hidden="true" mdbTooltip="Inactive Item" placement="bottom"></i><small class="text-muted"> 0</small>
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
        <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>View Details</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a data with a field of `item.status` and has a value of zero and one only. If the value of `item.status` is zero then the number beside the grey circle will increment while the number beside the green circle will increment if the `item.status` value is one.

also I am confuse if the `*ngFor` is properly use of my concern or not.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `*ngFor` is for repeating items in your template. I think for your use case you should rather do that processing inside your component code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I thought `ngFor` is like a for loop that you can use if you want to iterate anything.

Comment: You can loop over stuff, but it's purpose is strictly for building up your HTML repeating a template for each element in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

`ngFor` is not the right choice for what you want to do. `ngFor` is used when you want to render multiple UI elements. In your code sample, this line means "render one div for each element in the array `items`".

Write a loop in your TypeScript code calculating two numbers based on the app logic you described. In the component template, bind these numbers next to the respective circles.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I thought `ngFor` is like a for loop that you can use if you want to iterate anything.

Honestly I am very new in angular, so basically all `ng` in angular is for rendering a UI elements. if I want to put some logic 
inside my app what I need to change is the ts file and instead of searching about angular what I need to search is about typescript?

Comment: You need to learn how to write loops in TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

Answer (score 1):

You should loop in side your typescript and bind total count values to the html.

---

ts

```
let totalOneCount = 0;
let totalZeroCount = 0;

for(i=0;i<item.length;i++){
        if(item[i].status == 1) {
             totalOneCount++;
             continue;
         }
        totalZeroCount++;
    }
```

---

html

```
<div class="card-footer clearfix">
<div class="float-left p-2">
    <i class="fa fa-circle green-text" aria-hidden="true" mdbTooltip="Active Item" placement="bottom"></i><small class="text-muted"> {{totalOneCount}}</small>
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o grey-text ml-3" aria-hidden="true" mdbTooltip="Inactive Item" placement="bottom"></i><small class="text-muted"> {{totalZeroCount}}</small>
</div>
<div class="float-right">
    <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>View Details</a>
</div>
</div>
```

---

I hope this helps. If it does not work feel free to reach me with comments.